# Jenkins script: Run a new container in the POST block if the condition equals failure

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers

I have followed the [Jenkins documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/) to successfully run Jenkins and `docke:dind` in a container. I have a Jenkins script to build a Puppeteer image and run the container to test my frontend. I would like to add logic that terminates the current Puppeteer container and runs a new one if the testing fails.

Here is my Jenkins Script:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Dockerfile'
            dir 'MyDockerFileFolder'
            additionalBuildArgs  '--build-arg UID=$(id -u) --build-arg GID=$(id -g) -t puppeteer-testing-image'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm ci'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm run myPuppeteerTest'
            }
            post {
                failure {
                    // I would like to terminate puppeteer container here
                    // and run the new container here
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

If I simply add this command in the failure block, it won't work because the command is actually running inside the Puppeteer container, and the Puppeteer container doesn't have the Docker command.

```
sh 'docker run -name newContainer container:latest'
```

I am very new to Jenkins, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For your case, it's not suite to use top agent, you can try as following

```
def testContainer

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
            stage('Prepare') {
                steps {
                    testContainer = docker
                        .build(
                            '<image tag>', 
                            '''-f MyDockerFileFolder/Dockerfile \
                                 --build-arg UID=$(id -u) \
                                 --build-arg GID=$(id -g) \
                                 -t puppeteer-testing-image'''
                        )
                        .run('-u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -dt', 'cat')
                }
            }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    docker exec -it ${testContainer.id} npm ci
                """
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    docker exec -it ${testContainer.id} npm run myPuppeteerTest
                """
            }
            post {
                failure {
                    // I would like to terminate puppeteer container here
                    // and run the new container here
                    if(testContainer) {
                        sh """
                            docker stop ${testContainer.id}
                            docker run <for new container>
                        """
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```